# Search and filter in MS Access forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Background: I have a table named 'SNR_log', out of which I have queried to obtain below list.[image: table SNR_Log]

Next,I designed a split form, with a text box.In this text box SNR is enterted to find and filter from the list. To perform this operation 'Apply filter' macro is used with a where condition,

```js
[SNR] Like "*" & [Forms]![SNR_History]![Text17] & "*"
```

Problem: Is it possible to filter by inserting SNR in the textbox and obtaining the below result.
[image: here UID is filtered]

In other words, with SNR as input, display UID and all the SNR under that UID.

Comment: Could a Main form and SubForm setup not sort it out for you? With the textbox being the control that filters the subform?

Comment: I think I'm not able to define this way 'Show each SNR in UID using SNR' using your method.

Comment: Have you tried using a ComboBox instead of a text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around it in a simple way. I created a main form and subform. The record source for subform is the text box where SNR is entered. Once a command button is clicked with following event procedure in it I obtained the desired result;

```js
Private Sub Command4_Click()
 Text0.SetFocus
 Me.SNR_log_Subform.Form.RecordSource = "Select * from SNR_Log where UID in(Select UID from SNR_Log where SNR like '*" & Text0.Text & "*')"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do this in an "Apply Filter" macro.  You're going to need some VBA behind the scenes.

The first thing you want to do is query your data for the UID.  You would do that like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim Rec as Recordset
Dim UIDx as Integer
Dim strSQL as String
Dim strSQL2 as String

Set db = CurrentDB
strSQL = "SELECT UID FROM SNR_Log " & _
          "WHERE [SNR] Like ""*" & [Forms]![SNR_History]![Text17] & "*""
Set Rec = db.OpenRecordSet(strSQL)

'Now grab the UID that's returned and put it inside a variable
UIDx = Rec(0)
```

Now you have your UID that you want to query on.  So set up your RecordSource based on that:

```
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM SNR_Log WHERE [UID] = " & UIDx & ""

Forms!Me!frmSubFormName.RecordSource = strSQL2
Forms!Me!frmSubFormName.ReQuery
```

That will change the record source of the form, and refresh the form so it's looking at the current record source you just set it to.

You may have to putz with strSQL a bit, I can't remember exactly how to work with the **Like** operator inside a SQL string.  I'm pretty sure it's correct, though.

Comment: I respect your method Sir. Thank you for the help and time.